# Windows Named Pipes connections

Tags: windows, named-pipes

I have search high and low for this answer. Can one code up a Named Pipes server where the connection that a client makes is persistent until you close the applications? This would be in C/C++. Not asking any one to actually do this, as I am capable. To explain in a little more detail if my question is not clear, I want to be able to have the client connect to the server and then be able to pass data back and forth without having to kill the connection at the end of each data transaction and then start a new one again for the next. It seams that in every example I have seen or read, the transaction only lasted for that one data exchange. That seems wasteful and extremely time consuming. Then I want to thread it so I can have up to 8 clients on the same named pipe. If you know of example code that does this, that would be great also. Already read the Microsoft examples, and they seem to be single data exchanges with new connections every time.

My confusion lies with the readfile() and writefile() functions. They need the pipe handle and pointers to the data structures just like a file R/W on the hard drive. Those files can be opened at program start, used, and then finally closed just before you exit your application. There are risks to doing this, but sometimes necessary. So I want my server application to be in control not the clients.

Thanks in advance. I will answer any questions if this is not clear to you.

Comment: It's one pipe instance per client connection, but we can of course connect/disconnect to reuse instances in the pool.

Comment: Sharing a pipe instance with multiple clients isn't possible. Consider functions such as `GetNamedPipeClientComputerName`, `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId`, `GetNamedPipeClientSessionId`, and `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient`. All of this is designed for one client connection per instance, which goes straight to the fundamental implementation of the named-pipe filesystem in npfs.sys and how they're implemented over SMB.

Answer (score 0):

I am not surprised at your answers. I was really wanting a way to keep the connection open per instance, but since this is not how pipes work, I get it. I have devised a better way to make my applications talk to each other. I originally had one server and many clients, so I turned that around and now have one client and many servers each with a different pipe name. Since my client, that was the server, did most of the initiating of the messages, I can now manage better they way I send and request the data via messages/pipes. The only draw back is not giving the data to all of them at once, but what is a few microseconds amount friends. Please let me know if this will not work as I expect it will, before I spend a lot of time on the code. Thanks. Any suggestions are welcomed.